# How to make custom flow from directory with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Keras [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) looks like having strange biased design: while directory flow it expects that all images have single classes and distributed by subdirectories of the class name.

In my case I have each image having several classes and they are stored in CSV file in the same directory as images (in many-hot encoding).

Is it possible to feed Keras with such data (so that not load everything in memory)?

Comment: Try to have at look at this issue: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3338

Comment: You can explore the idea of creating python generators associated with the keras method `fit_generator`.